# Applying reduce between two values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

On a website, I have a set of entry fields for users to insert a selection of values. I currently have some JavaScript that finds the highest value that was entered into the array, and stores the index position of that particular value in a variable named HighValPos.

This is the code for it:

```
var HighValPos = inputtedVals.reduce((highestInd, TheValue, TheValueInd) => {
    return TheValue > inputtedVals[highestInd] ? TheValueInd : highestInd;
}, 0);
```

The problem I have is fundamentally a syntax issue; what I would like to do is only apply this `.reduce()` logic to array elements whose index value is between these two variables:

```
var firstEl = 0
var lastEl = 6
```

What can I try next?

Comment: `reduce` passes the current index to the callback function, so I suppose you could do it via that. But it would probably make much more sense, if you extracted the values from index 0 to 6 into a new array, and then run the existing code on that.

Comment: "*The problem I have is fundamentally a syntax issue;*" narrowing down to given indexes is not a syntactic issue. It's just logic, as in "how do I make the code obey these rules". Syntax would be about the rules of the language "what is a valid code construct".

Comment: With that said "how do I make `.reduce()` only apply between two indexes" is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425154/question-closed-was-my-explanation-poor-or-is-it-an-xy-problem). The most straight forward way to do it is to *not* enforce the limits through `.reduce()` but just do `arr.slice(start, end).reduce(existingReducerFn)`.